# Detect unpost of ttk::combobox

Tags: combobox, tcl, tk-toolkit, ttk

I have a Tcl/Tk program. In it I have a combobox, like so:

```
set cb [ttk::combobox .cb -state readonly -textvariable selection -postcommand [list choices .cb]]
```

The proc `choices` runs when the combobox posts, which is what I want. My question is, how do I detect when the combobox unposts?

I've tried both binding on `<<ComboboxSelected>>` and setting a variable trace on `selection`. The problem with each is that they only fire when the user actually changes the selection. I need some way to always detect when the combobox unposts.

Thanks!

**edit**

*What I'm trying to accomplish:* When the combobox posts it presents the user with a list of options. I don't expect the user to know what the options mean, therefor I am highlighting the options visually in a different area of my program. I have this highlighting triggering and working well with `-postcommand`. The issue is to know when to turn the highlighting back off.

`<<ComboboxSelected>>` doesn't fire if the user doesn't change the selected value.

`<Leave>` and `<FocusOut>` fire too soon (e.g. as soon as the box posts).

Comment: You could bind to <Leave>.

Comment: I've tried both <Leave> and <FocusOut>. They both seem to fire right after the combobox posts (i.e. as soon as the cb is clicked on), which is too soon. I think when the combobox posts, it creates a floating listbox which gets focus. I want a way to know when the floating listbox is destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

The combobox's popdown is actually its own nest of windows, and if your combobox is called `.cb` then the popdown has the imaginative name `.cb.popdown` (**note** that this *implementation* and is not guaranteed). If you add a binding to that widget's `<Unmap>` event you'll get to see the unposting; `<Unmap>` events are exactly the notifications sent when a window ceases to be displayed in the virtual desktop layer sense (as opposed to just ceasing to be visible, say because there's another window on top; there's events for that too, but they're not cross-platform).

The tricky bits:

- The popdown is usually created when needed, i.e., the first time it appears. You need the window to exist (but not necessarily be visible) before you bind to it. You can get the handle of the popdown widget with `ttk::combobox::PopdownWindow`, which will make the widget if it doesn't already exist. (It's part of the implementation, but it is more likely to be stable than the name.)

  ```
  set popdown [ttk::combobox::PopdownWindow .cb]
  bind $popdown <Unmap> {yourCallback %W}
  ```

  It is possible to dig around within the internal arrangement of the popdown, but I don't recommend it; it's *much* more likely to change without warning.
- Binding to the toplevel has the usual issues with events also being delivered for subwindows. Your callback should check that the event it has been given is *actually* for the toplevel:

  ```
  proc yourCallback {w} {
      if {$w ne [winfo toplevel $w]} { return }
      # The rest of your code here...
  }
  ```

Comment: Can you tell me where I can find documentation for `ttk::combobox::PopdownWindow`? It's not here: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/ttk_combobox.htm

Answer (score 1):

The window name of the listbox used by ttk::combobox is:

```
set popdown [ttk::combobox::PopdownWindow .combobox].f.l
```

I believe this is what you need.

```
bind <Leave> $popdown mycommand
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My combobox doesn't have a child called `.f.1`. I ran `winfo children` on it though, and it does have a child called `.popdown`. If I bind to `$combobox.popdown` it seems to work, but only intermittently.

I'm also worried that this won't be a good cross platform solution, or even that it will be stable between versions of Tk.

Comment: Should be .f.<ell>, not .f.<one>

Comment: The `[ttk::combobox::PopdownWindow .combobox].f.l` works cross platform.   I wish they had a ttk::combobox::PopdownListbox command, but otherwise it is safe. `ttk::combobox::PopdownWindow` will make sure the listbox window exists, so I would not use `$combobox.popdown` directly.